# Change Axis of Scatter Chart in Power BI

Tags: d3.js, typescript, powerbi

I need to change the type of the Axis in the orginal code of Enhanced Scatter Chart, i need to but a DATE column instead of COUNT of DATE, I am trying to edit the orginal code of the visualization. But i have no idea how to do it right. it tried to do the following :

I changed the following line :

```
xScale = <D3.Scale.LinearScale>this.xAxisProperties.scale,
```

into :

```
xScale = <d3.time.scale>this.xAxisProperties.scale,
```

also i tried to change all the X axises  from a string into Number.

Any idea how to change it or is it possible to do such a thing ?